# Select the authors with specific row

Tags: mysql

Defined a number - the number of the current article.
There is a table of `authors`:

```
id | post_id | autor
```

Need to select the list of authors, adding a column indicating whether a given author in this article.

Example:

```
id | post_id | autor
 1      33      Jacob
 2      35      Mike
 3      31      John
 4      35      Jacob
 5      33      Andrew
```

Need get for article 35:

```
autor | use
Jacob    1
Mike     1
John     0
Andrew   0
```

I use query for select autors:

```
SELECT a.`autor`, (
 SELECT count(*) as `count`
 FROM `autors` 
 WHERE `post_id`=35 AND `autor`=a.autor 
)
FROM `autors` a
GROUP BY `autor`
ORDER BY `autor` DESC
```

How to optimize this query?

Comment: This would be way easier if you had a normalized structure with an authors table and a seperate post_authors table.

Comment: This is Wordpress plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a1.autor, 
       (CASE WHEN a2.post_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1) AS `use`
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * 
      FROM `autors`    
      ORDER BY `autor` DESC) AS a1
LEFT JOIN autors AS a2 ON (a1.autor=a2.autor AND a2.post_id=?)
```

Something like this should work.